# Using an expression for an angular ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Somewhere in a controller:

```
$scope.foo = {'name': 'user_name', 'bindTo': 'user.name'};
```

Then on the html:

```
<label for="user_name">User Name</label>
<input name="{{foo.name}}" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="{{foo.bindTo}}"/>
```

This throws:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'foo.bindTo' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{foo.bindTo}}] starting at [foo.bindTo}}]
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964278/angularjs-bind-ng-model-to-a-variable-which-name-is-stored-inside-another-vari

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind the input to `$scope.user.name`, right?
I had a similar problem. What I do is similar to your structure:

```
$scope.foo = { 'name' : 'name', 'bindTo' : $scope.user };
```

And the HTML:

```
<label for="{{ foo.name }}">User Name</label>
<input name="{{foo.name}}" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="foo.bindTo[foo.name]"/>
```