# AngularJS Custom directive on same HTML element as ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wrote a simple directive to be able to dynamically set the value of ng-model, as described in this other Stack Overflow question: [AngularJS - bind ng-model to a variable which name is stored inside another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964278/angularjs-bind-ng-model-to-a-variable-which-name-is-stored-inside-another-vari?rq=1).  This works great, except when I use it on an element that also has an ng-repeat.  It gets rendered too many times and the DOM does not look correct.

Directive:

```js
angular.module( 'dynamicModel-directive', [] )
.directive( 'dynamicModel', function( $compile ) {
    return {
        link: function( scope, element, attr ){
            element[0].removeAttribute( 'dynamic-model' );
            element[0].setAttribute( 'ng-model', scope.$eval( attr.dynamicModel ) );
            $compile( element[0] )( scope );
        }
    };
});
```

HTML (simplified by rendering an input box instead of a button group):

```html
<div ng-if="field.type == 'buttonGroup'">
     <input type="text" ng-repeat="option in field.options"
           dynamic-model="field.name" class="form-control">
</div>
```

The above code results in four input boxes being displayed, even though there are only two items in field.options.

Here is what the resulting DOM looks like:

```html
<div ng-if="field.type == 'buttonGroup'" class="ng-scope">
<!-- ngRepeat: option in field.options -->
<!-- ngRepeat: option in field.options -->
<input type="text" ng-repeat="option in field.options" class="form-control ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="application.insured.gender">
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in field.options -->
<input type="text" ng-repeat="option in field.options" class="form-control ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="application.insured.gender">
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in field.options -->
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in field.options -->
<!-- ngRepeat: option in field.options -->
<input type="text" ng-repeat="option in field.options" class="form-control ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="application.insured.gender">
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in field.options -->
<input type="text" ng-repeat="option in field.options" class="form-control ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="application.insured.gender">
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in field.options -->
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in field.options -->
```

When I comment out the $compile line in the directive it displays the appropriate number of times so I think it is related to that, but I am not sure how to fix it.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want 2 inputs to have the same ng-model? Is it a radio input?

Comment: It's a button group that acts as radio buttons using the btn-radio AngularUI directive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the `ng-repeat` is got compiled multiple times.

You could set the `terminal` flag and raise the `priority` to be higher than `ng-repeat` to ensure that the `ng-repeat` will be compiled only once.

```
.directive('dynamicModel', function ($compile) {
  return {
    terminal: true, // prevent ng-repeat from compiled twice
    priority: 1001, // must higher than ng-repeat
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('ngModel', scope.$eval(attrs.dynamicModel));
      attrs.$set('dynamicModel', null);
      $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  };
});
```

PS. There is the `attrs.$set()`.

Comment: Here is a working example that I was working on before runTarm beat me to it: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/EJsLi