# angular- get ng-model name from scope var

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is any way to do it?

```
  ng-model="{{att.myModel}}"
```

I have an array named     AllSmallText  with items. I want to build form using ng-repeat on AllSmallText  and put ng-model value to be myModel which is one of the item field.

```
   <div ng-repeat="att in AllSmallText" class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
           <input class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="{{att.title}}"  type="text"
              ng-model="{{att.myModel}}"
              required autofocus />
   </div>
```

thanks

Comment: I want to use ng-model name with name stored in att.myModel

Comment: check this q/a which might help you. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964278/angularjs-bind-ng-model-to-a-variable-which-name-is-stored-inside-another-vari

Answer (score 2):

You don't need curly braces, use `ng-model='attr.myModel'`.

**Updated Answer**

`ngModel` will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the expression on the current scope.
If the property doesn't already exist on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

Add a new scope,

```
$scope.myForm = {};
```

And use `ng-model="myForm[attr.myModel]"`, this will created a new scope property like `$scope.myForm.hello`

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not what I want. I defined in my scope : attr.myModel = "hello" and I want that the ng-model will be hello

Comment: @user3944498 You will have to use [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) or [`$scope.$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for anything in this way, you can use the following syntax:

instead of ng-model="{{att.myModel}}" use ng-model="[att.myModel]"

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you could approach it and that is by adding the ng-model directive via another directive.

You could have an add-model directive in your markup:

```
<input type="text" add-model="{{myModel}}" />
```

And then in the directive add the ng-model:

```
myApp.directive('addModel', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var model = attrs.addModel;
            element.attr('ng-model',  model);
            element.removeAttr('add-model');  // avoid infinite loop
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oligustafsson/wuqqxtqu/