# Replace ng-model value with the value of scope attribute into "new" scope directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set the value of ng-model in my input box to the value of **scope.modelName** into the directive:

```
<input ng-model="{{modelName}}">
```

But that is not legal and generates an error, what is the best expression there to do that ?

The final HTML result must be:

```
<input ng-model="username">
```

The case here is special because the scope is "renewed" into the directive and that input is located inside the directive:

```
app.directive("textbox", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    replace: false,
    scope: true,
    templateUrl : "directives/textbox.html",
    link: function (scope,element, attr) {
        scope.modelName = attr.name;
    }
  };
});
```

That directive should be used as following:

```
<textbox name="username"></textbox>
```

In the normal cases, the following example is working:

```
<input ng-model="modelName">
```

But when i use that with my case it generates the same without any change to the ng-model value !

Comment: Try `ng-model="[modelName]"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964278/angularjs-bind-ng-model-to-a-variable-which-name-is-stored-inside-another-vari

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for:

```
<input ng-model="modelName">
```

The handlebars aren't needed

Comment: Yeah, that's working in normal way. I will update the question for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Update from

```
<input ng-model="{{modelName}}">
```

to

```
<input ng-model="modelName">
```

For reference - [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Answer (score 2):

I assume output that you are looking for should be equivalent of `<input value="username">` and not `<input ng-model="username">` (as stated in your question).

To resolve your problem, you should make use of `<input ng-model="modelName">`. There is no need of curly brackets.